# Löwenheim-Skolem for Lindström's Theorems

Tags: logic

In **Mathematical Logic** by Ebbinghaus/Flum/Thomas the Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem worded like this:

> Every satisfiable and at most countable set of formulas is satisfiable over a domain which is at most countable.

In a later chapter about the Lindström-Theorems it's changed to this:

> Every satisfiable sentence of L has an at most countable model.

Is this second formulation equivalent to the first one, or is it a weaker version?

Comment: See Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA151) (2nd ed - 2001), page 151 : "**LöWENHEIM–SKOLEM THEOREM (1915)** : (a) Let $\Gamma$ be a satisfiable set of formulas in a countable language. Then $\Gamma$ is satisfiable in some countable structure. [...] The theorem was published by Löwenheim in 1915 for the case where $\Gamma$ is a singleton; Thoralf Skolem
in 1920 extended this to a possibly infinite $\Gamma$."

Comment: That clears things up! Thank you.